# Set up a button that can hold dynamic information

Tags: android, eclipse, button, navigation

im trying to set up a button that the user can press to take them to the next letter of the alphabet. I previously achieved this by creating 26 different classes and it was just too much time to achieve.

The green arrows LEFT AND RIGHT will be used to take the user to the previous or next letter from the letter that they are currently viewing.

I have tried using cases, if conditions and now run out of ideas ?

Its a simple issue with a complex side to it, all i want is to change the image and sound as the user clicks each letter. If you can help in any way it would actually resolve more than this one issue i have brought up. Thanks in advance.

Photo of the GUI.

[image]

Comment: 1 ImageView, 5 Buttons. Finished. Ah, of course, 26*2 (lower and upper case) Alphabet characters (wouldn't you **better** use a font character, maybe a nice font, in a TextView, instead?) and the graphics for the Buttons.

Comment: I have used a toggle button so user can toggle on and off and it will change image from Capital Letter to Small Letter so its only 26 classes plus a few more for splash and menu etc

Comment: You don't need a class for each letter. It sounds terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you're after. Assuming you have a set of 26 images, each representing a letter of the alphabet, you can define them in an int array like this (I've only gone so far as "d" for this example):

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d};
```

Your ImageView, for example, is:

```
ImageView letter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.letter);
```

An integer to set the previous/next image based on the index of int[] images:

```
int index;
```

Assuming your back/next buttons are backBtn and nextBtn, set up onClick listeners which will set the value of "index" on each click (we check that the onClick only executes if the value of index is within the bounds of int[] images (from 0 to images.length):

```
backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (index > 0) {
            letter.setImageResource(images[index]);
            index -= 1;
        }
    }
});

nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (index < images.length) {
            letter.setImageResource(images[index]);
            index += 1;
        }
    }
});
```

I didn't test any of this but I think it should work. Hopefully I didn't misunderstand you again ;)

Comment: Im unsure what you are meaning, can you explain better as im fairly new to android development.

Comment: Sorry, ,I misunderstood your question but give me a couple of minutes to edit the answer with what I think is more along the lines of what you were asking ;)

Comment: away to have a bash, it seems like a logical solution Ill keep you posted on outcome. Thanks again.

Comment: everything is working with no errors apart from this.
ImageView letter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btna);

Should I have ImageView - letter.....for each letter so x26 ?

Comment: No, just one ImageView is all you need. Check that it exists in your layout with the correct id (btna in your instance). Otherwise, glad it's working or at least pointing you to the right direction ;)